# tell if it was ajax or non ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

PHP - I have tested the following code but the following headers don't seem to send that it is javascript sending the request and not a non-javascript user

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:146
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryA9tyz4BRlSglKAWC
Cookie:PHPSESSID=2dc90d7cfbcb6058d1ca02fd6144c3bf
Host:dev.r.com
Origin:http://dev.r.com
Referer:http://dev.r.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
```

Here is the code I want to use to tell if ajax or not

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
        if(!IS_AJAX)
        {
            die('Restricted access');
        }
```

And here is the javascript I use

```
function sendstatus(){

    var status = document.getElementsByName("status").value;
    var uri = "/statusupdate";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();

    xhr.open("POST", uri, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            var r = xhr.responseText;
            // Handle response.
            alert(xhr.responseText);

        }
    }
    fd.append('status', status);
    // Initiate a multipart/form-data upload
    xhr.send(fd);
    return false;
}
```

if anyone knows why it would not know that this is a xmlhttprequest it would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no 100% reliable way to tell a request made by a XHR from any other kind of HTTP request.  You can check for a header like you're doing, but the XHR must be configured to send the header you're expecting to find so there's no guarantee that it will send it.  Also any non-XHR request could have that header attached, so using it as a security method is a really really really bad idea

Comment: There really isn't a guarantee that any given header is going to be sent for any given request.  Why do you need this anyway?  `'Restricted access'` isn't very "restricted" if the user can just make the request via JavaScript or spoof a header...

Comment: You can set custom header param and check it in php: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536752(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at lines 67 - 74 of jQuery's source code
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js

```
    if ( !options.crossDomain && !headers["X-Requested-With"] ) {
        headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    }

    // Set headers
    for ( i in headers ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( i, headers[ i ] );
    }
```

It is known to me, that Apache2 receives these headers, so You can detect 
if call is Ajax or not.

Comment: But we are not using jquery

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery just to look at it's source code, LOL :D

Comment: **Any** HTTP header can be easily spoofed

Comment: @hindmost am not using the http header as a security messeur but need to make sure that non-javascript users get taken back to the page they where on before they hit submit.